# Resize Recovery HD "Unable to resize because file system volume format does not support resizing"

Tags: disk-utility, partition, high-sierra

On my Early 2011 MacBookPro 17", I tried "diskutil resizeVolume disk0s3 660M", but it says "Unable to resize because file system volume format does not support resizing".

```
diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical): #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER

0: GUID_partition_scheme *750.2 GB disk0

1: EFI EFI 209.7 MB disk0s1

2: Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD 407.9 GB disk0s2

3: Apple_Boot Recovery HD 342.0 GB disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual): #: TYPE NAME SIZE IDENTIFIER 0: Apple_HFS Macintosh HD +407.5 GB disk1 Logical Volume on disk0s2 3B73C6E8-26E8-4C40-9234-233B295311E3 Unencrypted
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that you need to re-size the recovery partition? You should leave it alone.

Comment: From reading other comments, it appears the size of Recovery HD might be about 660MB but mine is 342GB. I could use that extra space in Macintosh HD partition for more storage, if its not needed for the Recovery HD. My total disk is a 750.2 GB.